# Regular non-root ssh users are able to access root directories

Tags: ssh

Regular non-root ssh users are able to access root directories such as:

```
/etc  
/bin
```

These users should only be able to access/view/edit files in their home directories. Any idea how I can fix this on our server? Maybe I need to reset up the folder permissions for the root directories?

Comment: `/etc` and `/bin` are no _root_ directories and your requirement is...not really thought through. Check this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/267019/how-can-i-prevent-users-accessing-anything-but-their-own-home-directory

Comment: What is the business need for people not to be able *in general* to read these files and directories?  It's worked pretty well for UNIX these past forty years.

Answer (score 4):

There is not a lot of detail in your question but based on your users needing access only to files within their home directories here are some suggestions:

- setup chroot. This is quite involved and requires copying libraries, binaries and config files from the OS to each users home environment (although this can be shared across multiple users).  This will give you an ssh login which locks them into their own home directory (or specific directory) and they can only access files within that directory structure. Google 'setup basic chroot environment'
- try a different approach and only allow sftp access and restrict openssh to a named list of users or a group of users. They can then use WinSCP or similar tool to edit files in their home directories. This is much simpler to setup and only involves editing your sshd_config file. However this will not allow any executables and is simply for editing files and basic file maintenance. Google 'restrict sftp users'
- the more radical approach is to edit the access permissions on the areas you want to restrict access from such as /etc but this is fraught with issues and certainly will cause problems with updates and new installations and is a maintenance nightmare. The answer linked by lenniey gives more detail on some of the above and the pitfalls.